# How would I go about making a console app like GIT

Tags: c#, ruby, console, console-application

I want to build an application that can run from the console where I can put it in my path on windows and be able to use it. Like git for example. I normally use C# and Ruby but I want to try to get it to work on a Windows and a Linux/Unix environment. I know I can build a console app with C# but I've only done dot net with it.

I want to be able to write anywhere at any time in the console something like

Say my application is called Bob

```
Bob (nameofmethod) (argument of method) (options, eg -i, -o, etc)
```

Any idea how I would start building this application?

Comment: There are a ton of options for `CLI` gems in Ruby. Look at `slop`, `thor`, `commander`,`main`, or since you want it to be like `git` checkout `gli` (Git Like Interface). You can get a ton of gems and tutorials by simply using google "ruby command line gems" should get you started.

Comment: Questions asking for references to resources are usually downvoted or closed. If just ask how to make such an app, you will get better responses.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware. I've only asked a few questions before. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A console app (like git) is just an executable in your path which accepts command line arguments. When you do

```
$ git pull origin master
```

You are running the program `git` with the three arguments `pull`, `origin`, `master`.

In Ruby, command line arguments are stored in the constant `ARGV` array. You can parse them yourself or use the [optparse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptParse.html) stdlib to do common parsing.

Command line Ruby apps usually have a shebang line, so that you can run `myscript` directly instead of `ruby myscript`:

```
#!/path/to/ruby
```

Another common feature is to check if the script is being run directly (rather than being loaded by a different script).

```
if __FILE__ == $0
  # stuff to do when script is run directly
end
```

Comment: Thank you. That's very helpful. I would upvote your answer, but I'm under 15 reps at this point.